# PHP File Upload Security Analysis

Tags: php, security, xss

I see that the file upload filtering that I have been using for a long time has been compromised.

When we look at our options for **image** upload, there are a few functions we can use. I relied on the finfo_open function to verify that the file is indeed an image, but it's not that secure.

```php
<?php


// file extension ( Bad )

$mime = end(explode('.','test.gif')); // VALID GIF

print_r($mime); // .gif

// getimagesize ( Worst )

$mime = getimagesize('test.gif')['mime']; // VALID GIF

print_r($mime); // image/gif

// FINFO ( A little good )

$finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
$mime = finfo_file($finfo, 'test.gif'); // VALID GIF

print_r($mime); // image/gif

?>
```

**Yes, but we have a problem. It returns as gif in the file below.**

test.gif

```
GIF89
<?php
```

I thought the finfo_open function would be more healthy, it misled me a lot.
I need your suggestions on this.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below . Steps 1,2 you are already handling.

1)Check and make sure the uploaded file extension is "gif"

2)Use mime_content_type  function or finfo_file function  to check if mime type is gif

3)Read the first four chars ( magic bytes)  of the file and make sure sure they are "GIF8" . For other types you need to use different magic bytes.

Below is more details about magic bytes for different files types.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures

4)You can use the imagecreatefromgif function  to create a temp gif  file out of the uploaded gif file.
If that gif create fails , means it is not a proper gif.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromgif.php

https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.image.php

[image: Gif Magic Bytes]

Comment: All options except to create a new image over the contents of the file are invalid in my opinion. Because these options are very open to manipulation.

Are you aware that PHP is trying something new in this regard?

Comment: Not aware of any new steps in php. Each of these steps will protect against  a specific type of attack and it is  better to have all these check to avoid different types of attacks .